# Como puedo lograr que el date picker quede libre pues se tapa con estos estilos

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Tengo estos estilos para un input `type='date'`, pero no consigo que los controles para desplegar el calendario queden libres. Puedo ingresar las fechas de manera manual con el teclado numérico pero no quisiera perder la opción del calendario.

```css
.form-label-group {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.form-label-group > input,
.form-label-group > label {
  height: 3.125rem;
  padding: .75rem;
}

.form-label-group > label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0; /* Override default `<label>` margin */
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #495057;
  /* pointer-events: none; */
  cursor: text; /* Match the input under the label */
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
}

.form-label-group input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}

.form-label-group input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}

.form-label-group input::-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}

.form-label-group input::-moz-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}

.form-label-group input::placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}

.form-label-group input:not(:placeholder-shown) {
  padding-top: 1.25rem;
  padding-bottom: .25rem;
}

.form-label-group input:not(:placeholder-shown) ~ label {
  padding-top: .25rem;
  padding-bottom: .25rem;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #777;
}

/* Fallback for Edge
-------------------------------------------------- */
@supports (-ms-ime-align: auto) {
  .form-label-group > label {
    display: none;
  }
  .form-label-group input::-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: #777;
  }
}

/* Fallback for IE
-------------------------------------------------- */
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
  .form-label-group > label {
    display: none;
  }
  .form-label-group input:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: #777;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="form-label-group m-5">
  <input
  id='id1'
    type="Date"
    class="form-control invalid"
    placeholder="Texto"
   
  />

  <label for="id1">
    <span class="d-flex justify-content-between">
      Ingresa defecha
    </span>
  </label>

 
</div>
```

#### Actualización

La respuesta de [@Jacobo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/346260/33391) al problema da solución de manera parcial al disminuir el tamaño, pero en el caso de que yo agregue un elemento de texto más a la etiqueta para que se muestre a la derecha este no aparecera hasta el borde (como puede ser un link). Como prevenir esto? He cambiado la reducción de manera vertical y este es el resultado.

```css
.form-label-group {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.form-label-group > input,
.form-label-group > label {
  height: 3.125rem;
  padding: .75rem;
}

.form-label-group > label {
background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25%;
  margin-bottom: 0; /* Override default `<label>` margin */
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #495057;
  /* pointer-events: none; */
  cursor: text; /* Match the input under the label */
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
}

.form-label-group input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}

.form-label-group input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}

.form-label-group input::-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}

.form-label-group input::-moz-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}

.form-label-group input::placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}

.form-label-group input:not(:placeholder-shown) {
  padding-top: 1.25rem;
  padding-bottom: .25rem;
}

.form-label-group input:not(:placeholder-shown) ~ label {
  padding-top: .25rem;
  padding-bottom: .25rem;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #777;
}

/* Fallback for Edge
-------------------------------------------------- */
@supports (-ms-ime-align: auto) {
  .form-label-group > label {
    display: none;
  }
  .form-label-group input::-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: #777;
  }
}

/* Fallback for IE
-------------------------------------------------- */
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
  .form-label-group > label {
    display: none;
  }
  .form-label-group input:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: #777;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="form-label-group m-5">
  <input
  id='id1'
    type="Date"
    class="form-control invalid"
    placeholder="Texto"
   
  />

  <label for="id1">
    <span class="d-flex justify-content-between">
      Ingresa defecha
      <a href='alert('Se muestra')'>Mostrar alerta</a>
    </span>
  </label>

 
</div>
```

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con que *queden libres*? Tu código funciona bien en el *snippet*, el elemento muestra correctamente el calendario al hacer `click` en el mismo. ¿Cuál sería el problema realmente?

Comment: En chrome no logro que se despliegue el calendario, dete picker para escoger la flecha.Que navegador usas?

Comment: Tienes razón, he probado en Chrome y no funciona, sin embargo con Firefox y Samsung si que funciona bien. Déjame probar un par de cosas, tiene que ver con las reglas CSS al parecer. Saludos

Comment: La respuesta de @Jacobo es la que da en el clavo, aunque él sugiere que coloques un valor de `width:85%`, yo verificaría antes la necesidad de darle ese valor, y en todo caso la forma de corregir el mismo de cara al diseño *responsive*. El tema es que con un `width` de 100% el elemento se superpone a los controles usados por la UI del `input` tipo `date` de Chrome.

Comment: @MauricioContreras revisa los comentarios que le hice y la modificación de mi pregunta por si tienes algún comentario sobre lo que estoy tratando de aplicar para remediar .

Comment: @Angel modifique mi respuesta por lo que entiendo que es tu nuevo problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Teniendo en cuenta los cambios a la pregunta he borrado lo que tenía. Puedes utilizar la opción **auto** para height, y el navegador calculará la altura.

```
height: auto;
```

Fuente: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height

```css
.form-label-group {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.form-label-group > input,
.form-label-group > label {
  height: 3.125rem;
  padding: .75rem;
}

.form-label-group > label {
background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-bottom: 0; /* Override default `<label>` margin */
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #495057;
  /* pointer-events: none; */
  cursor: text; /* Match the input under the label */
  border: 0;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
}

.form-label-group input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}

.form-label-group input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}

.form-label-group input::-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}

.form-label-group input::-moz-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}

.form-label-group input::placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}

.form-label-group input:not(:placeholder-shown) {
  padding-top: 1.25rem;
  padding-bottom: .25rem;
}

.form-label-group input:not(:placeholder-shown) ~ label {
  padding-top: .25rem;
  padding-bottom: .25rem;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #777;
}

/* Fallback for Edge
-------------------------------------------------- */
@supports (-ms-ime-align: auto) {
  .form-label-group > label {
    display: none;
  }
  .form-label-group input::-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: #777;
  }
}

/* Fallback for IE
-------------------------------------------------- */
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
  .form-label-group > label {
    display: none;
  }
  .form-label-group input:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: #777;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="form-label-group m-5">
  <input
  id='id1'
    type="Date"
    class="form-control invalid"
    placeholder="Texto"
   
  />

  <label for="id1">
    <span class="d-flex justify-content-between">
      Ingresa defecha
      <a href='alert('Se muestra')'>Mostrar alerta</a>
    </span>
  </label>

 
</div>
```

Comment: Hola. Dentro de la etiqueta, con ciertas opciones creo un link para que se muestre sobre las opciones (generalmente lo uso para mostrar una contraseña). Con esa linea sin comentar  no puedo dar click a ese link. Esa plantilla que publique la uso con los diferentes `types`

Comment: Ah, bien, entonces pongo otra opción que te permita dejar esa regla comentada. Veo que has actualizado la pregunta así que voy responder en función de esa actualización.

Answer (score 2):

En tu codigo solo cambia el tamaño de tu label  `width: 85%;` y listo

```
    display: block;
     width: 85%;
     margin-bottom: 0; /* Override default `<label>` margin */
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cree unos `div`  y les agregue la clase `class="p-2"` para que me mantenga alineado los div

tambien cambie  la clase `justify-content-between` por `justify-content-start`

espero te sirva.

```css
.form-label-group {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  padding-top: 0.5em;
}

.form-label-group > input,
.form-label-group > label {
  height: 3.125rem;
  padding: .75rem;
}

.form-label-group > label {
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25%;
  margin-bottom: 0; /* Override default `<label>` margin */
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #495057;
  /* pointer-events: none; */
  cursor: text; /* Match the input under the label */
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
  
}

.form-label-group input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}

.form-label-group input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}

.form-label-group input::-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}

.form-label-group input::-moz-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}

.form-label-group input::placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}

.form-label-group input:not(:placeholder-shown) {
  padding-top: 1.25rem;
  padding-bottom: .25rem;
}

.form-label-group input:not(:placeholder-shown) ~ label {
  padding-top: .25rem;
  padding-bottom: .25rem;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #777;
}

/* Fallback for Edge
-------------------------------------------------- */
@supports (-ms-ime-align: auto) {
  .form-label-group > label {
    display: none;
  }
  .form-label-group input::-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: #777;
  }
}

/* Fallback for IE
-------------------------------------------------- */
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
  .form-label-group > label {
    display: none;
  }
  .form-label-group input:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: #777;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="form-label-group m-5">
  <input
  id='id1'
    type="Date"
    class="form-control invalid"
    placeholder="Texto"
   
  />

  <label for="id1" >
    <span class="d-flex justify-content-start mb-3" >
    
    <div class="p-2">Ingresa fecha</div>
    <div  class="p-2"> <a href='alert('Se muestra')'>Mostrar alerta</a> </div>
    </span>
   
  </label>

 
</div>
```

Comment: Pues ese no es el problema, he probado en Chrome, tal como sugiere el OP y no muestra el panel de calendario.

Comment: Yo estoy usando Chrome  y me funciona bien intenta borrar cache  o una venta de incógnito.

Comment: Nop, el resultado es el mismo. No funciona, ni incógnito ni cahe borrada. De hecho yo no uso Chrome, lo instalé únicamente para realizar la prueba. Saludos

Comment: Bueno entonces no se,  no puedo hacer más yo, ya que a mi si funciona con mis cambios jajaja te adjunto imagen de resultado de mi navegador, saludos.

Comment: Pues funciona. Solo que no estoy muy satisfecho con el echo de reducir el tamaño de la etiqueta. En general, en el label después de `"Ingresa fecha"` ocupo poner un dato más y con `justify-content-between` lo manda hasta la derecha. Con esta opción queda más hacia el centro. Actualize mi pregunta para ver este efecto. Que no había puesto en la pregunta inicial.

Comment: @Jacobo He tomado tu idea de reducir la etiqueta, pero en vez de hacerlo horizontalmente lo hice en vertical. Checa mi pregunta, la actualice con esta aplicacion.

Comment: @Angel listo modifique mi respuesta con lo que entiendo que es tu problema

Answer (score 0):

bueno que te parece si hacemos lo que quieres pero con utilidades de bootstrap

mira este ejemplo y lo mejor es que no necesitas personalizar tantos estilos :)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<div class="position-relative m-5">
  <input
  id='id1'
    type="Date"
    class="form-control h-auto pt-3"
  />

  <label for="id1" class="position-absolute" style="
    top: 0;
    padding-left: 0.8rem;
font-size: 12px;
color: #777;
">
      Ingresa defecha
  </label>
  
</div>
```

quite tus estilos y solo coloque los necesarios en linea, los demas son estilos de bootstrap

Comment: @BetaM ya así sirve?

Comment: Ok si ya es más clara

Comment: Hola. Los estilos son para otras funciones que omiti. Ciertamente es más limpio como lo pones pero en mi caso ocupo esas líneas... aunque no todas O: